# Graph and matrix at the same height

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I tried to place a matrix and a graph side by side, but I do not know, how to do it. I found something, but it did not work. (I am beginner.) Thank's.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
[shorten >=1pt,->]
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=blue!25,minimum size=12pt,inner sep=2pt]
\node[vertex] (10) at (1,-1)  [shape=circle,draw=black] {1};
\node[vertex] (11) at (3,-1) [shape=circle,draw=black] {2};
\node[vertex] (12) at (2,-2) [shape=circle,draw=black] {3};
\node[vertex] (13) at (1,-3) [shape=circle,draw=black] {4};
\node[vertex] (14) at (3,-3) [shape=circle,draw=black] {5};
\draw (10) edge[-] (11);
\draw (10) edge[-] (12);
\draw (11) edge[-] (12);
\draw (13) edge[-] (14);
\draw (12) edge[-] (13);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip -2cm
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\centering
0&1&1&0&0 \\
1&0&1&0&0 \\
1&1&0&1&0 \\
0&0&1&0&1 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
%\end{minipage}
\begin{center} 
    Obr. 5
\end{center}
~\\
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Is the `Obr, 5` meant to be placed right below the matrix? Note that the `\centering` inside the `tikzpicture` and `bmatrix` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I did not know it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly *not* use a minipage for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}%<-- added, 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,baseline=(12.base)]
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle,fill=blue!25,minimum size=12pt,inner sep=2pt}}
\node[vertex] (10) at (1,-1)  [shape=circle,draw=black] {1};
\node[vertex] (11) at (3,-1) [shape=circle,draw=black] {2};
\node[vertex] (12) at (2,-2) [shape=circle,draw=black] {3};
\node[vertex] (13) at (1,-3) [shape=circle,draw=black] {4};
\node[vertex] (14) at (3,-3) [shape=circle,draw=black] {5};
\draw (10) edge[-] (11);
\draw (10) edge[-] (12);
\draw (11) edge[-] (12);
\draw (13) edge[-] (14);
\draw (12) edge[-] (13);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1&0&0 \\
1&0&1&0&0 \\
1&1&0&1&0 \\
0&0&1&0&1 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

In case `Obr. 5` denotes something like `figure 5`, put the thing in a figure environment.

[image]

Comment: @Euler In order to increase the space, simply replace `\quad` by `\qquad`, `\quad\quad\quad` or `\hspace*{1cm}` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use `minipage`, in the example below I set up two of them, each

```
of them using 30% of the width of the page

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}

% graph
\begin{tikzpicture}
[shorten >=1pt,->]
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=blue!25,minimum size=12pt,inner sep=2pt]
\node[vertex] (10) at (1,-1)  [shape=circle,draw=black] {1};
\node[vertex] (11) at (3,-1) [shape=circle,draw=black] {2};
\node[vertex] (12) at (2,-2) [shape=circle,draw=black] {3};
\node[vertex] (13) at (1,-3) [shape=circle,draw=black] {4};
\node[vertex] (14) at (3,-3) [shape=circle,draw=black] {5};
\draw (10) edge[-] (11);
\draw (10) edge[-] (12);
\draw (11) edge[-] (12);
\draw (13) edge[-] (14);
\draw (12) edge[-] (13);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}

% matrix
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  \centering
  0&1&1&0&0 \\
  1&0&1&0&0 \\
  1&1&0&1&0 \\
  0&0&1&0&1 \\
  0&0&0&1&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to make the matrix part of the `tikzpicture`, by placing it in a `\node`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  shorten >=1pt,
  vertex/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=blue!25,minimum size=12pt,inner sep=2pt}
]
\node[vertex] (10) at (1,-1)  {1};
\node[vertex] (11) at (3,-1)  {2};
\node[vertex] (12) at (2,-2)  {3};
\node[vertex] (13) at (1,-3)  {4};
\node[vertex] (14) at (3,-3)  {5};

% simpler way of drawing the connections
\draw (12) -- (10) -- (11) -- (12) -- (13) -- (14);


\node [
  label=below:Obr. 5, % adds Obr. 5 below the matrix
  right=of current bounding box.east, % position it relative to everything made so far in the diagram
] {
$\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1&0&0 \\
1&0&1&0&0 \\
1&1&0&1&0 \\
0&0&1&0&1 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```